google.api_core.exceptions.InternalServerError: 500 when trying to create embeddings with text-embedding-004 and PGVector.from_documents
I'm trying to create embeddings for a large collection of documents. I'm splitting them into chunks, then using PGVector to add them to my database. My embed model is text-embedding-004.
I can't get through a full iteration of this process, no matter how slow I make it execute (I'm batching the embeddings call to run no more than 50 splits per 70 seconds). I know the embed model and connection string are correct; I DO get through a few iterations. But without fail, I always get a 500 error eventually:
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555509Z langchain_google_genai._common.GoogleGenerativeAIError: Error embedding content: 500 An internal error has occurred. Please retry or report in https://developers.generativeai.google/guide/troubleshooting
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555497Z raise GoogleGenerativeAIError(f"Error embedding content: {e}") from e
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555489Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_google_genai/embeddings.py", line 86, in _embed
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555485Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555481Z return self._embed(texts, task_type=task_type)
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555476Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_google_genai/embeddings.py", line 103, in embed_documents
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555472Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555467Z embeddings = embedding.embed_documents(list(texts))
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555463Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/pgvector.py", line 1009, in from_texts
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555457Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555453Z return cls.from_texts(
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555444Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/pgvector.py", line 1139, in from_documents
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555440Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ERROR 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555437Z Traceback (most recent call last): File "/app/genai_coach/management/rag_pipelines/school_resources_rag_pipeline.py", line 137, in create_embeddings vectorstore = PGVector.from_documents(
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555422Z The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555417Z google.api_core.exceptions.InternalServerError: 500 An internal error has occurred. Please retry or report in https://developers.generativeai.google/guide/troubleshooting
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555405Z raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555402Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 78, in error_remapped_callable
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555398Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555394Z return func(*args, **kwargs)
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555391Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py", line 120, in func_with_timeout
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555387Z ^^^^^^^^
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555383Z result = target()
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555380Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/api_core/retry/retry_unary.py", line 144, in retry_target
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555376Z raise final_exc from source_exc
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555372Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/api_core/retry/retry_base.py", line 212, in _retry_error_helper
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555368Z _retry_error_helper(
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555364Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/api_core/retry/retry_unary.py", line 153, in retry_target
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555360Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555356Z return retry_target(
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555353Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/api_core/retry/retry_unary.py", line 293, in retry_wrapped_func
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555342Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555338Z return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555335Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 131, in __call__
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555326Z ^^^^
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555322Z response = rpc(
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555318Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/ai/generativelanguage_v1beta/services/generative_service/client.py", line 1093, in batch_embed_contents
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555314Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555309Z embedding_response = client.batch_embed_contents(embedding_request)
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555304Z File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/generativeai/embedding.py", line 156, in embed_content
DEFAULT 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555288Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ERROR 2024-12-03T23:14:30.555283Z Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_google_genai/embeddings.py", line 79, in _embed result = genai.embed_content(

def get_embed_model() -> Embeddings:
    return GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings(
        model="models/text-embedding-004", google_api_key=settings.GOOGLE_API_KEY
    )
splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=200)
splits = splitter.split_documents(documents)
PGVector.from_documents(
    splits,
    embed_model,
    collection_name=self.collection_name,
    connection_string=connection_string,
    pre_delete_collection=should_delete_collection,
    use_jsonb=True,
)

